# Swift - Overlay is not showing over AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer

Tags: swift, camera, avfoundation, overlay

I'm trying to put an overlay on the preview layer but for some reason the UIImageView that I add to the preview layer is not shown.

Code:

```
let session = AVCaptureSession()
let sessionQueue = DispatchQueue(label: AVCaptureSession.self.description(), attributes: [], target: nil)
let imgView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 240, height: 80))

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    imgView.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: "angleArm.png")

    session.beginConfiguration()
    let videoDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInDualCamera, for: AVMediaType.video, position: .back)
    if (videoDevice != nil) {
        let videoDeviceInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoDevice!)
        if (videoDeviceInput != nil) {
            if (session.canAddInput(videoDeviceInput!)) {
                session.addInput(videoDeviceInput!)
            }
        }
    }

    session.commitConfiguration()

    let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session)
    previewLayer.frame = view.frame

    previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)

    let preView = UIView()
    preView.frame = self.view.frame
    preView.addSubview(imgView)
    self.view.addSubview(preView)
    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(preView)

}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    sessionQueue.async {
        self.session.startRunning()
    }
}
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    sessionQueue.async {
        self.session.stopRunning()
    }
}
```

I've read some posts and tried to use CALayer and add the imageView to its contents and as of now I tried creating another UIView, put the imageView in it and add it to the main view, but still no luck.

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should check and change zPosition of overlay view. I think you should put overlayView.layer.zPosition > preview.layer.zPosition.

For example code:
overlayView.layer.zPosition = preview.layer.zPosition + 1

Comment: I've added `preView.layer.zPosition = self.view.layer.zPosition + 1` after `self.view.bringSubviewToFront(preView)` but still its not showing.

Comment: you try set previewLayer.zPosition = -1

Comment: Still nothing. I have it set like this: `previewLayer.zPosition = -1
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
        
        let preView = UIView()
        preView.frame = self.view.frame
        preView.addSubview(imgView)
        self.view.addSubview(preView)
        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(preView)
        preView.layer.zPosition = self.view.layer.zPosition + 1` and still the overlay doesn't show up.

Answer (score 0):

You try set previewLayer.zPosition = -1.